# jQuery not updating after window resize / positioning

Tags: jquery, css, resize

If you make browser window smaller, refresh the page and maximize the window, the navigation bar will be in the same place instead of sticking to the bottom (it goes back to bottom when you refresh the page). How to fix this?

Also, how can I center vertically items inside #menu (or .navigation)?

https://jsfiddle.net/jywe8zqj/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var menu = $('#menu');
   var windowH = $(window).height();
   var stickToBot = windowH - menu.outerHeight(true);
   menu.css('top', stickToBot + 'px');
        
   $(window).scroll(function() {
     var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();
     if (scrollVal > stickToBot) {
       menu.css({top: '0px', position: 'fixed'});
     }
     else {
       menu.css({top: stickToBot + 'px', position: 'absolute'});
     }
  });
 });
```

```css
html,body {
  min-width:320px;
  min-height:320px;
  margin:0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  text-align:center;
}

h1 {
  margin-top:0;
  font-size:68px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
#menu {
    z-index:99;
    width: 100%;
    min-height:80px;
    height: 10%;
    background:white;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;

}
.header-wrapper {
  background-image: url("images/backgrounds/typography.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  min-height:calc(90vh - 6em);
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:6em;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
}
.tester{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  bottom:50px;
  margin: auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.tester a{
  margin-left:1em;
  margin-right:1em;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.tester a:hover{
  opacity:1;
}
.slider-buttons {
  position:absolute;
  max-width:1170px;
}
.typography {
  bottom: 100px;
  left:auto;
}
.navigation {
  max-width:1170px;
  margin:0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}

nav {
  float:right;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#626262;
  padding:40px 20px 40px 20px;
  margin:0;
}
nav #home:hover, #menu2:hover, #menu3:hover, #menu4:hover, #menu5:hover {
  color:white;
}
nav #home:hover {
  background-color:#dfbb42;
}
nav #menu2:hover {
  background-color:#c43434;
}
nav #menu3:hover {
  background-color:#508b61;
}
nav #menu4:hover {
  background-color:#428d9e;
}
nav #menu5:hover {
  background-color:#575fbd;
}


#logo {
  float:left;
  margin-left:30px;
}

.text-boxes-wrapper{
  padding: 2em 0 2em 0;
  background-color:#f1f1f1;
}
.text-boxes {
  position:relative;
  max-width:1170px;
  margin:0 auto;
  height:450px;
  padding:3em;
}
.text-box-content{
  max-width:500px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  text-align:left;
  padding:1em;
  background-color:white;
}

#box1, #box2, #box3, #box4 {
  position:absolute;
  padding:2em;
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:2em;
}

#box1 {
  background-color:#428d9e;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
#box2 {
  background-color:#c43434;
  top:0;
  right:0;
}
#box3 {
  background-color:#dfbb42;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
}
#box4 {
  background-color:#508b61;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>random title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="menusticker.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<section>
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <h1>random heading</h1>
    <div class="tester">
      <a href="">          
        <div class="typography">
          <img src="images/slider-buttons/typography/typography-icon.jpg">
          <img src="images/slider-buttons/typography/typography-text.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <div class="typography">
          <img src="images/slider-buttons/rwd/rwd-icon.jpg">
          <img src="images/slider-buttons/rwd/rwd-text.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <div class="typography">
          <img src="images/slider-buttons/ux/ux-icon.jpg">
          <img src="images/slider-buttons/ux/ux-text.jpg">
        </div>
      </a>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



<section id="menu">
  <div class="navigation">
    <nav>
    <a href="" target="_top" id="home">Home</a>
    <a href="#text-boxes" id="menu2">Menu 2</a>
    <a href="#picture-boxes-section" id="menu3">Menu 3</a>
    <a href="" id="menu4">Menu 4</a>
    <a href="" id="menu5">Menu 5</a>
  </nav>
  <img src="css/images/logo.png" alt="Logo" id="logo">
</div>
</section>


<section id="text-boxes">
  <div class="text-boxes-wrapper">
    <div class="text-boxes">
      <a href="" id="box1">BOX NAME 1</a>
      <a href="" id="box2">BOX NAME 2</a>
      <a href="" id="box3">BOX NAME 3</a>
      <a href="" id="box4">BOX NAME 4</a>
      <div id="text-box-content">
        <h2>Text from box name 1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ornare turpis nec mauris scelerisque, sed suscipit elit dapibus. Aliquam ut eros sed risus convallis venenatis eget vitae mi. Cras dictum est non nunc semper blandit. Quisque convallis tristique dolor eget ultrices. Mauris ac orci quis neque facilisis laoreet. Suspendisse vitae ultrices ipsum, at placerat eros. Proin varius malesuada ultricies. Cras a metus elementum, pellentesque libero eu, faucibus lorem. Integer ac ornare lacus. Ut pretium felis tellus, nec faucibus eros rhoncus eget. Pellentesque ultrices, ligula vestibulum porttitor pharetra, arcu nisl vulputate ligula, id vulputate ligula urna vel tortor. In ullamcorper blandit erat, nec egestas massa commodo consectetur. In nec odio lorem. Donec nulla neque, vehicula in bibendum et, rhoncus sit amet nibh.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You should add a minimal Complete verifiable example to the post.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong (I'm a beginner so I might not understand everything) but it's in jsfiddle, right?

Comment: External links can break, Some people (myself included) do'n't bother to follow links to remote places to look at code. You will get more eyes on it if it is in the question.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Editing my first post then!